# Kendall tau distance

Tags: list, comparison

[the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) explains the Kendall tau edit distance but doesn't say too much about possible applications. When or for what do you use the tau distance? 
I'm searching for real world examples, not invented examples of mathematics.

Comment: This is more applicable to statistics than programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendall Tau can be used as a metric to compare similarities between search results. For example, one can compare how close the top-10 results produced by Google and Bing (for the same query) are.

Comment: Can you please give me an example

Comment: Suppose you want to measure how good a ranking algorithm is. Assume that the correct ranked order of objects (given by an oracle) is: O(1,2,3,4,5). Now, you run your ranking algorithm A and the result ranked order is: A(1, 2, 3, 5, 4). Kendall Tau allows you to quantify how close the ranking produced by A is to that provided by the oracle. The intuition is that it gives how many swaps one has to perform to turn, in this example, A into O.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by finding similarities between tuples.  Read "Programming Collective Intelligence" to see what real life applications look like.  Think Netflix.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with a set of video elements from YouTube. These videos have features like the number of comments or the length of the title. Some but not all of them have an average rating or likes and dislikes. To make a quality statement about those, I looked at the correlation between the ground truth quality statements and other features. As it turns out, there are some significant correlations, for example, the comment count correlates with the average rating. So I can assume the comment count of a video infavor of its quality.

[Example from SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kendalltau.html#scipy.stats.kendalltau) (think of `x1` and `x2` as `comment_count` and `rating_average`):

```
>>> x1 = [12, 2, 1, 12, 2]
>>> x2 = [1, 4, 7, 1, 0]
>>> tau, p_value = sp.stats.kendalltau(x1, x2)
>>> tau
-0.47140452079103173
>>> p_value
0.24821309157521476
```